# ¿Es posible hacer un componente html manualmente?

Tags: html

estoy haciendo un proyecto que consiste en una pagina web, mi pregunta es si es posible hacer comoponentes HTML como los de angular pero manualmente.

Pregunto esto porque estoy usando funciones como navbar que tienen que estar en todas las subpaginas, y me gustaria poder modularlo y facilitarme la vida.

Edicion: Voy a agregar datos importantes que pase por alto, pido mis disculpas por dicha falta de respeto.

Tengo un Navbar presente en cada subpagina para navegacion dentro del sitio web. Sin embargo tengo que agregar el codigo completo del navbar en cada archivo que esta dentro del sitio web (digase, Subir alumno/Ver alumno), intente hacer el codigo de navbar como un codigo aparte y hacer llamado con etiquetas (ej: ) pero no lo pude hacer. 
[image]

Comment: Lo que quieres es crear Elementos Html más complejos como lo es el menú y que solo sea incluirlo en las páginas, entendí bien?

Comment: Como dijo el chavo del ocho: eso eso eso eso

He intentado por mi cuenta pero no he podido hacerlo

Comment: muestranos lo que has intentado por favor?? a partir de ahi podemos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Ahi añadi lo que he hecho hasta ahora, pido disculpas por no hacerlo antes

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer "componentes" utilizando php por ejemplo: podrías hacer un archivo llamado secciones.php en él puedes hacer funciones de cada sección que se repita en otros documentos html, así cuando necesites reutilizar un sección solo tengas que llamar a la función y no tengas que reescribir todo el html desde cero. Solo tienes que incluir tu archivo secciones.php dentro de la nueva plantilla y llamar a la función que necesites, ejemplo:
Tienes un archivo que se llama historia.php en el cual vas a utilizar el header, el nav y el footer del index (pagina principal) quedaría mas o menos así.

```
<pre>
<?php
 include('secciones.php);
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php 
   header();
  ?>

<?php 
   navbar();
  ?>
  //Codigo html

  <?php 
   footer();
  ?>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

Así llamas a las funciones que contienen el html en las posiciones que necesites y ahorras tiempo y tu codigo no es tan extenso.

Comment: O sea que usando ese codigo hago el componente (por ejemplo navbar), lo llamo "navbar.php", ¿Y despues en index hago include ('navbar.php') ?

Comment: Exacto, es la forma más efectiva que conozco para hacer esto

Comment: Asi es brou haces ya se un solo archivo o un archivo para cada seccion ya depende de ti como se te haga mas facil, y lo llamas en la posición que necesites. si me aguantas te dejo un ejemplo funcional, es que ando en la chamba.